# phantomjs location encoding

Tags: encoding, phantomjs, url-encoding

I'm trying to get two params with phantomjs (location, title) from urls. Some of that urls have russian characters in them. Urls titles also have russian characters. Question is, why I have no problem with titles and a big problem with locations encoding (page.url). For example when I treat url [http://terrareligiosa.jimdo.com/лекторий](http://terrareligiosa.jimdo.com/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) with

```
page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
    console.log(system.args[1])
    console.log(page.url)
    console.log(page.title)
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I get an output

> [http://terrareligiosa.jimdo.com/лекторий](http://terrareligiosa.jimdo.com/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)
>
> http://terrareligiosa.jimdo.com/????????
>
> Главная - terrareligiosas Jimdo-Page!